# Exceptions in deserializing List<T> in another DLL

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

In a inherited project, attempting to deserialize a generic List in a dll different from the dll that serialized the list, I obtain exceptions.

The generic in the list is the following class

```
[Serializable]
    public class NodeData
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
        public byte ImageIndex { get; set; }
        public int IDRx { get; set; }
  
    }
```

The method that deserialize it

```
public static T Deserialize <T> (string serializationFile)
{
    //T NodesData = new List<NodeData>();
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter
        {
            Binder = new NodeDataLoaderDeserializationBinder()
        };

        var result = bformatter.Deserialize(stream);


        T NodesData = (T)result;
        return NodesData;
    }
    
}
```

I have also created a custom SerializationBinder with a BindToType method implemented in this way

```
public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
{
    Type typeToDeserialize;

    var tn = typeof(List<NodeData>).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(tn, true);

    return typeToDeserialize;
}
```

What the method has given me back is that exception

```
 An object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [Utility.NodeData] []' cannot be converted to type 'Utility.NodeData []'.
```

If I change the typeof in BindToType method with NodeData[] I get:

```
 Reference to an object not set to an object instance.
```

How I have to implement my BindToType method?

Comment: **DON'T** use BinaryFormatter for **any** reason. This class [has unfixable security problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-5.0#remarks), is obsolete and marked for removal from .NET. It's functionality is *already* being removed from .NET. What happened here is just one of the problems caused by it - the tiniest difference in types can break deserialization, because `BinaryFormatter` serializes *everything*, including fields and type names.

Comment: If you want binary serialization, use one of the many cross-platform formats available like Protocol Buffers, Avro, Parquet, Orc etc. Protocol Buffers is a good choice as .NET already supports it through [its gRPC tooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), or through libraries like StackExchange's [Protobut-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net)